# Creating a base repository class with a generic dbcontext property

Tags: c#

In my project I have multiple `DbContext` classes that each contains specific Entity classes that can be used for specific cases.
I want to create a Repository base class in which a DbContext class of type T can be injected. The second reason for doing this is that writing unit tests would be al lot easier.

I have the following code so far:

```
public interface IDbContextRepository<T>
{
    public T Context { get; }
}

public class DbContextRepository<T> : IDbContextRepository<T>
{
    private readonly T _context;

    public DbContextRepository(T context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T Context { get { return _context; } }
}
```

Now I want to use the above in my repository classes like this:

```
public interface IMyRepository : IDbContextRepository<AreaDatabaseContext>
{
    IList<Item> GetItems();
}

public class MyRepository : DbContextRepository<AreaDatabaseContext>, IMyRepository
{
    public AccorderenRepository(AreaDatabaseContextcontext) : base(context) { }

    public IList<Item> GetItems()
    {
        using(var db = new Context())
        {
            //database operations
        }
    }
}
```

I'm registering the repositories in the following way:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<IDbContextRepository<AreaDatabaseContext>, DbContextRepository<AreaDatabaseContext>>();
```

When starting the application I encounter the following errormessage:
`Unable to resolve service for type 'AreaDatabaseContext'`

As a follow up question: am I going down the right path with this at all or am I opening a can of worms because I would have to handle of management of said Datacontext?

Comment: A DbContext is already a generic, base multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work that's meant to be scoped. It doesn't need to be wrapped in yet another "repository". Your code breaks the UoW semantics. A DbContext *is* the UoW itself. It tracks all pending changes and persists all of them in a single internal database transaction when `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: `writing unit tests would be al lot easier.` it's not hard to begin with. What's the *actual* problem you want to solve? What you tried to do isn't only trying to fix what isn't broken, it actually breaks what works very well already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So I am actually going down the wrong path, thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: You need to register the `AreaDatabaseContext` too. Generally I wouldn't do what you're doing. It's possible sure, but what's the point of all this abstraction? Just create your different repositories for your different use cases and have them inject the context they need. I don't see the value of abstracting over the trivial fact that all your repositories rely on some kind of context.

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve?